# Assign many values to an element of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I want to assign to an element of a list only one value I use always a `dictionary`. For example:

```
{'Monday':1, 'Tuesday':2,...'Friday':5,..}
```

But I want to assign to one element of a list `many values`, like for example:

```
Monday: Jogging, Swimming, Skating
Tuesday: School, Work, Dinner, Cinema
...
Friday: Doctor
```

Is any built-in structure or a simple way to make something like this in python? 
`My idea:` I was thinking about something like: a dictionary which as a `key` holds a day and as a `value` holds a list, but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Assigning a list as a value in a dictionary sounds perfect to me.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense Ok, thanks! So I will use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary whose values are lists is perfectly fine, and in fact very common.

In fact, you might want to consider an extension to that: a `collections.defaultdict(list)`. This will create a new empty list the first time you access any key, so you can write code like this:

```
d[day].append(activity)
```

… instead of this:

```
if not day in d:
    d[day] = []
d[day].append(activity)
```

The down-side of a `defaultdict` is that you no longer have a way to detect that a key is missing in your lookup code, because it will automatically create a new one. If that matters, use a regular `dict` together with the `setdefault` method:

```
d.setdefault(day, []).append(activity)
```

You *could* wrap either of these solutions up in a "MultiDict" class that encapsulates the fact that it's a dictionary of lists, but the dictionary-of-lists idea is such a common idiom that it really isn't necessary to hide it.

Comment: It was the first and the simplest idea which I though of, so I am happy that in your opinion it is a good idea. And I don't need to hide that in a class.

Comment: @Ziva - From the [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): _"Simple is better than complex."_ ;)

Comment: @iCodez From now I will remember about this :)

Comment: @Ziva: Also from the Zen: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." So often, the first answer that comes to mind is the right answer. (But not always, as the next line, and the hidden joke about the dashes, implies; part of becoming an experienced Python programmer is getting into the frame of mind where "obvious" means the same thing to you as to the language and stdlib designers:)